# Adding new recipe to Yocto fails during generate root fs

Tags: yocto

I have been using Yocto to create Linux builds for an ARM board.

I had been cross compiling add on applications manually. Now we are in a place where we would like a nice integrated build so I started adding custom recipes to yocto.

I have been struggling with the ARM build (a x86 build with the same code seems fine).

Even a basic 'hello world' pretty much cut and paste from the development manual does not work (http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-writing-a-new-recipe)

Here is the recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

RPROVIDES_${PN} = "helloworld"

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld ${LDFLAGS}
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: helloworld not found in the base feeds (smarc_samx6i cortexa9t2hf-vfp-neon-mx6qdl cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6qdl cortexa9t2hf-vfp-neon cortexa9t2hf-vfp cortexa9hf-vfp-neon cortexa9hf-vfp armv7at2hf-vfp-neon armv7ahf-vfp-neon armv7at2hf-vfp armv7ahf-vfp armv6thf-vfp armv6hf-vfp armv5tehf-vfp armv5ehf-vfp armv5thf-vfp armv5hf-vfp noarch any all).
ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

Any suggestions as to what would be causing this error?

The package does build properly; the problem seems to be isolated to finding it for the rootfs.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have a solution that seems to work, although it is not ideal long term.

Changing the package name under IMAGE_INSTALL from helloworld to helloworld-0.0.1 resolves the issue. Obviously I would rather not hard code the version of each package in the top level recipe and other packages do not require this, so hopefully there is another solution.

EDIT 2:
Renaming the recipe and removing the version string also resolves the issue. Once again, this does not seem ideal long term.

Comment: Where have you stored your recipe (which directory) and how is its file name?

Comment: I created a 'meta-test' location in sources, and a 'recipes-test' location under that. There is a layers.conf for meta-test.

Comment: Did you add `meta-test` to bblayers.conf ?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the bblayers.conf file. As a quick test if it's removed I get an error that nothing provides the package. Adding back in eliminates this.

Comment: I should point out that I can install the build packages onto a target machine successfully. The problem is isolated to building the image.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some further testing I discovered this was a naming issue with the recipe.

It was named helloworld-0.0.1.bb (the same format with the other recipes I had put together driving me to try this simple test).

If anyone else encounters this simply replacing the '-' with a '_' resolves this.

Answer (score 0):

1.Rename your recipe name e.g hello-0.1.bb  to hello_0.1.bb

2.Add below line at last only:

```
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
```

Abvoe line helps you copy your binary to rootfs.